# how to output data from xampp to Textview

Tags: android, json, android-studio, xampp

the code below I have successfully displayed the data but using the recyclerView. I want to ask how to display data if using Textview?

```
private void loadDataMahasiswa() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.setMessage("Loading ...");
        progress.show();

        String nip = editTxtnip.getText().toString();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        LoginAPI api = retrofit.create(LoginAPI.class);
        Call<Value> call = api.view3(nip);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Value>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Value> call, Response<Value> response) {
                String value = response.body().getValue();
                progress.dismiss();
                if (value.equals("1")) {

                    results = response.body().getResult();
                    viewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter3(Lihat_izin.this, results);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Value> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

---

[the results of the variables above are not readable sir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svAv2.png)

---

```
<?php
require_once('dbConnect.php');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') 
  $opd = $_GET['opd'];{
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)FROM(SELECT DISTINCT waktu,status from absen_pagi where opd='$opd' AND waktu='$timestamp')as dt";
  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $result = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result, array('waktu'=>$row['COUNT(*)']));
  }
  echo json_encode(array("value"=>1,"result"=>$result));
  mysqli_close($con);
}
```

this my php json

Comment: are you using only simple data to showing or arrayList?

Comment: simple data to showing

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ArrayList of data then just add this line inside the response body
See below code

```
public void onResponse(Call<Value> call, Response<Value> response) {
                String value = response.body().getValue();
                progress.dismiss();
                if (value.equals("1")) {
                    results = response.body().getResult();
                    viewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter3(Lihat_izin.this, results);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);
                    String myData = response.body().toString(); // convert data to string
                    textView.setText(myData); // just add data to textView
                }
            }
```

Let me know if not solved yet

Comment: do you have to use   viewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter3(Lihat_izin.this, results);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);
?

Comment: @tantinadevega these code required when you want to show any arrayList of data in recyclerView. If you just want to show any single data to textView. It not required any adapter to call. Just add response to textView. That's why I already mention in my answer.

Comment: is there no more value called?

Comment: @tantinadevega have you tried my code yet?

Comment: I have tried, the error occurred in my phpjson using an array, how to get the array in the text view, do I have to change my script in my php?

Comment: @tantinadevega Have you created a Pojo class file for getting ArrayList of API?

Comment: done but still null, while I try in post man there is a value

Comment: @tantinadevega I asked that have you created Pojo Class for getting API?

Comment: I have tried the results of the program which is printed com.myaplication code

Comment: do you know the code to call pojo?

Comment: see this https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I mean call and display on android